# Memory allocation of nested char pointer

Tags: c, string, struct, initialization, allocation

I have a question regarding the allocation of memory for a given char pointer inside a struct. The following typedef bson_value_t is given by an API and I would like to use it inside my own typedef ObjectInfo, shown in my code:

```
typedef struct _bson_value_t {
    bson_type_t value_type;
    union {
        int64_t v_int64;
        int32_t v_int32;
        int8_t v_int8;
        double v_double;
        struct {
            uint32_t len;
            char *str;
        } v_utf8;
    } value;
} bson_value_t;

typedef struct _ObjectInfo {
    char key[100];
    bson_value_t value;
} ObjectInfo;
```

I have other data packages that contain hundreds of these ObjectInfo types, but all simply initalized like:

```
typedef _DataPackage {
    ObjectInfo single;
    ObjectInfo multiple[100];
    ...
} Datapackage;
```

So they do not contain any usefull data yet. I would like to use strcpy to put a string to the location where char *str is pointing. But as far as I know that does not work because there is no allocated memory where *str is pointing to, right?
My question would be, how do I accomplish that without changing the given typedef bson_value_t? Do I need to allocate memory for any one bson_value_t that I initialized?

```
strcpy(DataPackage.single.value.value.v_utf8.str, "test");
```

That does not work, unless I change it to:

```
strcpy(&DataPackage.single.value.value.v_utf8.str, "test");
```

but this is giving me compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to use strcpy to put a string to the location where char *str is pointing. But as far as I know that does not work because there is no allocated memory where *str is pointing to, right?

Right.

> My question would be, how do I accomplish that without changing the given typedef bson_value_t? Do I need to allocate memory for any one `bson_value_t` that I initialized?

No, you do not (for this purpose) need to dynamically allocate memory for any `bson_value_t`.  The space, if any, to which any of those `value.v_utf8.str` members point will be external to the the `bson_value_t`, so arranging for that memory is a separate consideration.

As far as the data structure itself is concerned, the string data could be dynamically allocated, or they could be statically allocated (such as the contents of a string literal), or they could even be a locally-declared array (automatically allocated), though this last will present issues if the lifetime of the string data is shorter than that of the `bson_value_t`.

However, do make sure that you know what assumptions are made by the library from which you are drawing this.  For example, if any of its functions assume that they can reallocate space to provide for lengthening the string, or if they assume that they can modify the contents in place, then such assumptions affect what kind of storage you need to provide.

Comment: Ok my question was somehow misleading, sry. If I have a DataPackage with let’s say 1000 ObjectInfos that all contain one bson_value_t, and I want every one of the *str pointers to point to an empty string of a known character length, so I can later simply fill the strings in my main program. Do I need to manually allocate memory and assign it to each *str pointer in multiple for loops and so on, or is there a way around it?

Comment: @Psoke, instead of multiple allocations in loop, you can make 1 big allocation. But assignments you still will need to do in a loop.